# Error when deployed an MVC site in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

Recently, I deployed an MVC site builded in VS2013 into Azure. In fact, I have been done 4 deployments so far. The frist tree were deployed OK.

It was untel the last deployment when I'm getting an error saying: That the  tag needs to be added in the web.config.

It's weird because while testin git locally I didn't get any error. Until, I deployed it to Azure.

This is the error I'm getting when running it in Azure:

```
Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current    custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
   <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
   <configuration>
      <system.web>
         <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
      </system.web>
   </configuration>
```

The changes that I did in this last deployment was to Add some columns using the First Code creation approach, as well as the data migration itself.

Again, locally all works OK. But, once it is in Azure it doesn't.

Any clue, helo, approach?

Comment: Can you give exact details of the error message you are getting?

Comment: You likely have an unhandled exception, maybe due to something like an incorrect database connection string (which is why it'd work locally, but not when deployed).  The screen you are seeing is telling you that you can update the `<customErrors />` section of the web.config to see what the actual error is.  While you can do this temporarily to see the issue on Azure, it's not recommended to have this for a live site.

Answer (score 1):

After spending time googling what's happening I found the solution. However, another problem came.

First of all, I put the  tag in the web.config in order to see the errors.

Well, the thing here is that for some reason the Data Migration for the Code First was throwing an exception that was not caught. I added the following line of code in the Startup.Auth.cs file

```
OnException = context => {}
```

For more infor, visit: [Why is [Owin] throwing a null exception on new project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327092/why-is-owin-throwing-a-null-exception-on-new-project)

In that way, you can bypass the error. Now, if you want to know the exact error, then put:

```
OnException = (context =>{
             throw context.Exception;
             })
```

And you can see what was the error. Which in my case is: **The model backing the  context has changed since the database was created**

I followed the solution for this link: [The model backing the <Database> context has changed since the database was created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600175/the-model-backing-the-database-context-has-changed-since-the-database-was-crea)

And it solve the problem in some way.

Since I added two new columns to the AspNetUser table, those new columns are not present in the Azure tables saying the the columns doesn't exists. Even I have those columns added locally. Still figure out how to solve this. I guess I will create another post for this.

Hope this help others